# Difference between GetExtendedUdpTable and netstat result

Tags: c++, windows, api, port, netstat

I used this code to get opened UDP ports and the application that use every port.

```
DWORD (WINAPI *pGetExtendedUdpTable)(
  PVOID pUdpTable,
  PDWORD pdwSize,
  BOOL bOrder,
  ULONG ulAf,
  UDP_TABLE_CLASS TableClass,
  ULONG Reserved
);
    MIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID *pUDPInfo;
    MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID *owner;
    DWORD size;
    DWORD dwResult;

    HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)"iphlpapi.dll");

    pGetExtendedUdpTable = (DWORD (WINAPI *)(PVOID,PDWORD,BOOL,ULONG,UDP_TABLE_CLASS,ULONG))
        GetProcAddress(hLib, "GetExtendedTcpTable");

    if ( !pGetExtendedUdpTable )
    {
        //printf("Could not load iphlpapi.dll. This application is for Windows XP SP2 and up.\n");

        return "Could not load iphlpapi.dll. This application is for Windows XP SP2 and up.\n";
    }

    dwResult = pGetExtendedUdpTable(NULL,       &size, false, AF_INET, (UDP_TABLE_CLASS)5, 0);
    pUDPInfo = (MIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID*)malloc(size);
    dwResult = pGetExtendedUdpTable(pUDPInfo,   &size, false, AF_INET, (UDP_TABLE_CLASS)5, 0);
//
   if (dwResult != NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Couldn't get our IP table");

        return "Couldn't get our IP table";
    }
   for (DWORD dwLoop = 0; dwLoop < pUDPInfo->dwNumEntries; dwLoop++)
    {
        owner = &pUDPInfo->table[dwLoop];      
        ApplicationName = GetNameByPID(owner->dwOwningPid);
        OpenedPort = convertInt(ntohs(owner->dwLocalPort));
        LocalAdress = convertInt(ntohs(owner->dwLocalAddr));
   }
```

But, I haven't the same result as netstat -ano.In my code, I have port 0 more than 10 times but in netstat command port 0 doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have UDP everywhere but the function you're querying for is the TCP one (`GetExtendedTcpTable`).